# Segfault when using pytorch with rocm in linux

Tags: linux, pytorch, archlinux, amd-rocm

I have an amd rx 6600 and I am trying to use pytorch with rocm. I am running archlinux and using the package provided by the distro. When I try to access the gpu memory the program crashes. It seems that memory is being allocated but I cannot read the memory. Here's the code:

```py
import torch

# check for amd hip
print(torch.cuda.is_available())
print(torch.version.hip)

device = torch.device('cuda')
id = torch.cuda.current_device()
# print gpu name
print(torch.cuda.get_device_name(id))
# no memory is allocated at first
print(torch.cuda.memory_allocated(id))

# store some variable in gpu memory
r = torch.rand(16).to(device)
# memory is allocated
print(torch.cuda.memory_allocated(id))
# crashes when accessing r
print(r[0])
```

And here's the output:

```
 ~ ＞ python test.py
Tru                                                     # gpu compute is available
5.4.22804-                                              # rocm version
AMD Radeon RX 6600                                      # name of gpu
0                                                       # memory allocation at start
512                                                     # memory allocation after storing variable
zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  python test.py   # program crashes when reading variable
```

Is there something wrong with my code? How do I debug this? I want to be sure before submitting a bug report to the package maintainer. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

FYI I have just a simple AMD desktop and am a fairly Linux-proficient user but am by no means knowledgable, however, I was able to resolve this exact same issue with the following steps, ***although this is just a workaround, and does not originally solve your issue. For anyone that finds themselves here, I hope this helps as a hotfix while this is solved elsewhere.***

System specs:

- OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS x86_64
- Kernel: 5.19.0-41-generic
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 7900X (24) @ 4.700GHz
- GPU: AMD Radeon RX 6950 XT

tldr; try with caution! ensure your linux kernel builds properly etc.

````
sudo apt update; 
sudo apt install rocm-libs miopen-hip rccl; # this will install rocm dependencies, 14GB worth, so be patient!
pip install torch==1.13.0 torchvision==0.14.0 torchaudio==0.13.0 --index-url "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/rocm5.2";
pip install ipython;
ipython;

```sh
 In [1]: import torch
      ...: 
      ...: # check for amd hip
      ...: print(torch.cuda.is_available())
      ...: print(torch.version.hip)
      ...: 
      ...: device = torch.device('cuda')
      ...: id = torch.cuda.current_device()
      ...: # print gpu name
      ...: print(torch.cuda.get_device_name(id))
      ...: # no memory is allocated at first
      ...: print(torch.cuda.memory_allocated(id))
      ...: 
      ...: # store some variable in gpu memory
      ...: r = torch.rand(16).to(device)
      ...: # memory is allocated
      ...: print(torch.cuda.memory_allocated(id))
      ...: # crashes when accessing r
      ...: print(r[0])
      True
      5.2.21151-afdc89f8
      AMD Radeon RX 6950 XT
      0
      512
      tensor(0.3706, device='cuda:0')
 In [3]: torch.__version__
 Out[3]: '1.13.0+rocm5.2'

```
````

1. Ensure that your rocm works correctly. I've had to fix broken installs and only terrible experiences with package dependencies not resolving trying to use `amdgpu-install`, not to mention, holy moly the rocm docs are hard to read for a simple general user (as I identify as), and in general, I've found it to do a terrible install unless you're super familiar with AMD GPU architectures. Had better luck with just a plain old `apt-get`
2. Unfortunately, no matter what I have done, I *cannot* get rocm 5.4.2 to work properly with torch 2.0.0. This is a shame as there are considerable speedups and really new fancy things to play around with, but 1.13.0 is the best I could get working without a segfault popping on trying to send anything to the GPU, although I haven't tried to build from source.
3. This is an **optional** step (I'm not sure it actually fixed the problem) but in a previous attempt using `amdgpu-install` had errors building the `dkms` kernel (yikes) so I just went ahead and followed the steps here to ensure nothing surprising happened on restart (https://askubuntu.com/a/1240434/1416884).
4. Check your rocm version (there apparently isn't an easy way to do this? no idea why, but this is the best I found:

```bash
$ ll -ah /etc/alternatives/rocminfo 

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 Apr 25 22:31 /etc/alternatives/rocminfo -> /opt/rocm-5.4.3/bin/rocminfo
```

5. install pytorch 1.13.0 (with rocm 5.2, it's backward compatible, so anything after 5.2 **should** be alright, see this compatibility chart [here](https://docs.amd.com/bundle/ROCm-Deep-Learning-Guide-v5.4.3/page/Prerequisites.html), note that 1.13 is the highest supported version for pytorch)
6. Lastly, if you want a sample of an install script that installs with your python package, feel free to check this one out `[here]`, although it's under construction, it should work with just a `bash install.sh`

Alright, hope this helps!

Comment: I found a solution.

https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/78306

It seems rx 6600 only supported hip runtime by default. I think pytorch also needs support for hip sdk. So I had to use HSA_OVERRIDE_GFX_VERSION=10.3.0